# Spring boot 3.0 / Tomcat 10 support for JBPM

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jbpm, kogito

Currently JBPM officially support Spring boot version 2.5.15., but it is out of support from Spring.

Are there any plans for JBPM team to support Spring boot 3.x versions?

I tried to run jbpm using Spring boot 3., but 3.0 requires Tomcat 10(jakartaEE)., so getting exceptions for the same.

Also no new release of jbpm after 7.73.0 i.e. almost from last one year., so do we need to move something else?

Will we have new release from JBPM or should we switch to Kogito or some other BPMN or Serverless workflow tools?